# AngularJS: How to make the inner div visible

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have 3 divs of the same size stacked on each other. Each of the divs has got the size of the screen which is visualized on the image with the black frame.
What I would like to achieve is to make div2 visible at the beginning. This is means div2 is filling the screen and the other divs are just visible when I am swiping up or down.
Right now, div1 is visible at the beginning since it is the first div.

Any help?

[image: visible div in the middle]

```
<div id="wrapper" style="overflow:hidden" layout="column">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: assuming you are playing with angular you can create a ng-switch statement and initialize it with ng-init you can check for more on angularjs doc on this example https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

Comment: well thats not exactly what I want since I would like to show all 3 divs, but only the 2nd one at first on the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this library:

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js

HTML

```
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section" id="div1">a</div>
  <div class="section active" id="div2">b</div>
  <div class="section" id="div3">c</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#fullpage>div{
    height: 100vh;
}
```

In order to view the second square on page load add `active` class to the div.
Hope it helps.

Comment: This looks good. However I hoped to get some css only solution since this library is pretty large with jquery dependency and so on..nevertheless this is my best try so far, thanks!